# sysstat sar only collects cpu usage

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring, sar, sysstat

I'm running into a problem when using `sar` to collect live system statistics. When I run a sar command such as the following, I get the right output:

```
$ sar -r 1 -o /tmp/memory_usage
Linux 4.15.0-70-generic ()  29/12/20    _x86_64_    (60 CPU)

18:26:55    kbmemfree   kbavail kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty
18:26:56     30855140  78554416  51599624     62.58    321400  48906356   3491612      4.18  25558204  23859156        36
18:26:57     30855124  78554456  51599640     62.58    321400  48906392   3491612      4.18  25558204  23859212        72
18:26:58     30855204  78554536  51599560     62.58    321400  48906424   3491612      4.18  25558204  23859212       104
18:26:59     30855188  78554576  51599576     62.58    321400  48906456   3491612      4.18  25558204  23859268       136
18:27:00     30855204  78554648  51599560     62.58    321400  48906492   3491612      4.18  25558204  23859324       172
18:27:01     30855048  78554492  51599716     62.58    321400  48906524   3491612      4.18  25558228  23859324         0
^C
Average:     30855151  78554521  51599613     62.58    321400  48906441   3491612      4.18  25558208  23859249        87
```

However, when I load the output file, it seems to have only recorded the cpu usage?

```
$ sar -f /tmp/memory_usage
Linux 4.15.0-70-generic ()  29/12/20    _x86_64_    (60 CPU)

18:26:55        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
18:26:56        all      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.02     99.97
18:26:57        all      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.02     99.97
18:26:58        all      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.02     99.97
18:26:59        all      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.02     99.97
18:27:00        all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
18:27:01        all      0.02      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.02     99.95
Average:        all      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.01     99.97
```

This is my system's info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4.15.0-70-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 10:36:11 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm running sar 11.6.1, which was installed through apt, and I did not configure any cron data collection (if that matters), although I did enable the sysstat service:

```
$ systemctl status sysstat
● sysstat.service - Resets System Activity Data Collector
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sysstat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2020-12-29 16:56:29 GMT; 1h 34min ago
     Docs: man:sa1(8)
           man:sadc(8)
           man:sar(1)
  Process: 52376 ExecStart=/usr/lib/sysstat/debian-sa1 --boot (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 52376 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 29 16:56:29  systemd[1]: Starting Resets System Activity Data Collector...
Dec 29 16:56:29  systemd[1]: Started Resets System Activity Data Collector.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why is the memory usage not being recorded in the file? Did I misconfigure something, or is this not possible to achieve with `sar`? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an idiot, found the answer. Apparently when you tell `sar` to collect system statistics into a file, it outputs **everything** into it, not just the options you passed it.

So, what the command `sar -r 1 -o /tmp/memory_usage` is really saying is: "capture all options at a sample rate of one per second, and record them in the given file. *Also*, output the memory statistics to the terminal at the same rate".

Since all the stats are recorded in the output file, it can be queried with the same options as if it was live. The command `sar -r -f /tmp/memory_usage` outputs the memory usage collected from the file, as I expected.